# Referral traffic from queuecumber.corp.google.com

Tags: google, referrer

I've noticed some referral traffic today from `queuecumber.corp.google.com`

Following the referral source redirects you to Moma (I believe this is Google's intranet)

Now I'm wondering if this is Google's manual webspam team? What is Queuecumber?

EDIT: It appears that the visitor was in Hyderabad, which is also home to Google's largest India campus.

Comment: Since this is an internal Google server, there probably isn't a definitive way to answer this without hearing from somebody inside the Googleplex.  They have likely created some internal project and named it "queuecumber".   I'm not sure how we are going to divine what it does without a look behind the curtain.

Comment: There are also some open source projects with that name.   Maybe Google is running a server with this software?  https://github.com/MapKit/QueueCumber  Although that looks like it might be client side JavaScript, so doubtful.